# Create datasource for ColdBox application

Tags: coldfusion, datasource, commandbox

I am working on a legacy system written in ColdFusion. I am attempting to set up a local development environment. I have had some minor success getting the main login page to load from a ColdBox server. I created a directory:

```
$ mkdir myapp
$ cd myapp
$ box
```

Then from the ColdBox CLI:

```
CommandBox> coldbox create app
CommandBox> start
```

I also copy my legacy code to a subfolder of `myapp`:

```
$ cp <some path> legacy
```

Now I can navigate to `127.0.0.1:<port>/legacy` to get the login page for the project that I am working on. However, I can't login because there is no datasource configured with the authentication tables that my app expects. How do I configure a datasource to an existing database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get to the **ColdFusion Administrator**.

After you start the server you should see an icon on your taskbar (right side bottom corner), after you click on it, you should see something like this:

[image]

After you click on **Open Server Admin** you can login into ColdFusion Administrator, the user is `admin` and the default password is `commandbox`

You create your datasource in the **Data Sources** section

[image]

Alternatively, if you're going with **Adobe ColdFusion** engine you can open your browser and go to
 `127.0.0.1:<port>/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm`
or
 `127.0.0.1:<port>/legacy/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm`

If you're going with the **Lucee** engine then you have the `Server Admin` at `http://127.0.0.1:53227/lucee/admin/server.cfm` and the `Web Admin` at `http://127.0.0.1:53227/lucee/admin/web.cfm` and you'll have to set up your passwords the first time you go there.

Comment: I am developing in an Ubuntu VM. When I click on the equivalent menu, a blank box appears on my screen. I believe there is some rendering issue due to the VM. Is there a URL I can enter directly into my browser to get the admin console?

Comment: Try `127.0.0.1:<port>/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm`

Comment: I tried that and got a 404. I will try again tomorrow to double check.

Comment: Then you probably have the `Lucee` engine, I've updated my answer.

Comment: I will try those in the morning when I as back at the office

Comment: The addresses for the Lucee engine worked for me. I just had to change the port to the one that CommandBox used.